# currently logged in user’s ID not being saved in MYSQL DB (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, web

I am learning Web development using spring. I'm a complete beginner..

I have problem in my project.
there is a user logged in website. and user can create the party(= group).
but here a problem arose. current User's ID doesn't save in MYSQL DB.
I tested in postman. I logged in using the JWT token, entered the token, and ran the above test.

I can't solve this problem so I'm asking for your help..!

Below is My party DB table

**distribution_rate leader_id party_id party_name party_password serial_number**

NULL NULL 1 partyTest 123 #0001

The second part is leader_id, that is, a column that stores the ID of the currently logged in user. However, if you look at it, you can see that it is saved as NULL.

(I want to upload a picture, but I'm sorry I can't upload it because I don't have enough reputation yet.)

Below is part of my code.

**Party Entity**

```
package .dividendcalculator.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Parties")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Party {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "party_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "party_name")
    private String partyName;

    @Column(name = "party_password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "leader_id")
    private Member leader;

    private Double distributionRate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "party", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<PartyMember> partyMembers;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String serialNumber;

}
```

**PartyService**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PartyService {
    private final PartyRepository partyRepository;
    private final PartyMemberRepository partyMemberRepository;
    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;
    private final MemberRepository memberRepository; 
    @Autowired
    public PartyService(PartyRepository partyRepository, PartyMemberRepository partyMemberRepository, ItemRepository itemRepository, MemberRepository memberRepository) {
        this.partyRepository = partyRepository;
        this.partyMemberRepository = partyMemberRepository;
        this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
        this.memberRepository = memberRepository;
    }


    **// Party creation method
    public Party createParty(PartyCreateDto partyCreateDto, Member currentMember) {
        Party party = new Party();
        party.setPartyName(partyCreateDto.getName());
        party.setPassword(partyCreateDto.getPassword());

        // Check if leaderId is provided
        Long leaderId = partyCreateDto.getLeaderId();
        Member leader = null;
        if (leaderId != null && leaderId >= 0) {
            // Set leader information using leaderId
            leader = memberRepository.findById(leaderId)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("존재하지 않는 리더 ID: " + leaderId));
            party.setLeader(leader);
        }
        // If leaderId is missing or invalid, party is created without leader.

        // create serialNumber
        String serialNumber = generateSerialNumber(party);
        party.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);

        // save party
        Party savedParty = partyRepository.save(party);

        // Add leader as party member (only if there is a leader)
        if (leader != null) {
            PartyMember leaderPartyMember = new PartyMember();
            leaderPartyMember.setParty(savedParty);
            leaderPartyMember.setMember(leader);
            // leaderPartyMember.setDistributionRate(...);
            partyMemberRepository.save(leaderPartyMember);
        }

        return savedParty;
    }**


    

}
```

**PartyCreateDto**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PartyCreateDto {
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private Long leaderId;
}
```

**PartyController**

```
import .dividendcalculator.domain.Member;
import .dividendcalculator.domain.Party;
import .dividendcalculator.dto.item.ItemManageDto;
import .dividendcalculator.dto.party.*;
import .dividendcalculator.service.PartyMemberService;
import .dividendcalculator.service.PartyService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/parties")
public class PartyController {

    private final PartyService partyService;
    private final PartyMemberService partyMemberService;

    @Autowired
    public PartyController(PartyService partyService, PartyMemberService partyMemberService) {
        this.partyService = partyService;
        this.partyMemberService = partyMemberService;
    }

    // CreateParty
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Party> createParty(@RequestBody PartyCreateDto partyCreateDto, @AuthenticationPrincipal Member currentMember) {
        Party createdParty = partyService.createParty(partyCreateDto, currentMember);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(createdParty);
    }

    // Party 삭제
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteParty(@PathVariable Long id, @AuthenticationPrincipal Member currentMember) {
        partyService.deleteParty(id, currentMember);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    // 리더 ID에 의한 파티 조회
    @GetMapping("/leader/{leaderId}")
    public List<Party> getPartiesByLeader(@PathVariable Long leaderId) {
        return partyService.getPartiesByLeaderId(leaderId);
    }

    // 시리얼 넘버에 의한 파티 조회
    @GetMapping("/serial/{serialNumber}")
    public Party getPartyBySerialNumber(@PathVariable String serialNumber) {
        return partyService.getPartyBySerialNumber(serialNumber);
    }

    // 파티에 파티원 추가
    @PostMapping("/{partyId}/members")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addPartyMember(@PathVariable Long partyId, @RequestBody PartyMemberAddDto partyMemberAddDto) {
        partyMemberService.addPartyMember(partyId, partyMemberAddDto.getMemberId()); // 수정
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    // 파티원 업데이트
    @PutMapping("/{partyId}/members/{memberId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updatePartyMember(@PathVariable Long partyId, @PathVariable Long memberId, @RequestBody PartyMemberUpdateDto partyMemberUpdateDto) {
        partyMemberUpdateDto.setPartyMemberId(memberId); // ID 설정
        partyMemberService.updatePartyMember(partyMemberUpdateDto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{partyId}/members/{memberId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> removePartyMember(@PathVariable Long partyId, @PathVariable Long memberId) {
        // PartyMemberRemoveDto 대신 partyId와 memberId를 직접 사용
        partyMemberService.removePartyMemberByUserIdAndPartyId(memberId, partyId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    
}
```

I would like to solve the problem that the ID of the currently logged in user is not saved in the DB. Please help me.. Please.
What's wrong with my code?

I spent three days doing the best I could. I feel like I can no longer solve it alone, so I ask for help.